# Issue in building search with like query using QueryBuilder yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2, query-builder

I am trying to make a search query for my website blogs using yii2 QueryBuilder , but there is an error like this when i try to execute my query with `->all()` . here is the error : `strtr() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given` . And here is my model and controller . I have no idea what is causing the problem .

controller :

```
public function actionSearchBlog()
    {
        $model = new Blog();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Blog::searchBlog($model->search);
        } else {
            return $this->render('search',['model' => $model]);
        }
    }
```

Model :

```
public static function searchBlog($search = null)
    {
        $search = new Query();
        $result = $search->select('id','title','blog','picture')
          ->from('blog')
          ->where(['like' , 'title' , $search])
          ->orWhere(['like' , 'blog' , $search])
          ->all();
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($result);
        die();
    }
```

I tried the query without `->all()` at the end , but the `var_dump` value will be the the query itself and it won't be executed . and with `->all()` I get that error.

Comment: `$search = new Query;` and `->orWhere(['like' , 'blog' , $search])`. You passing object instead of string. Rename `$search = new Query;` to `$query = new Query;`

Comment: @ineersa i am trying to check the searched word in db with like query , what else can i do to perform this task ?

Comment: Start using good IDE, `public static function searchBlog($search = null)` and `$search = new Query();`. Are you kidding me or srsly don't see whats wrong in your code.

Comment: @ineersa OMG :O thank you , that conflict was because of an edit after writing the query :| , i totally missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static function searchBlog($search = null)
{
    $query = new Query();
    $result = $query->select('id','title','blog','picture')
      ->from('blog')
      ->where(['like' , 'title' , $search])
      ->orWhere(['like' , 'blog' , $search])
      ->all();
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($result);
    die();
}
```

This will work. But start using IDE, and watch on variables you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try your `ActiveQuery` as:--

```
$result = (new Query())->select('id','title','blog','picture')
        ->from('blog')
        ->where(['like' , 'title' , $search])
        ->orWhere(['like' , 'blog' , $search])
        ->all();

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($result);
    die();
```

Comment: as you see i have already created an instance of the query in $search variable so obviously thats not the case

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the $search is string or array?

> like: operand 1 should be a column or DB expression, and operand 2 be
>   a string or an array representing the values that the column or DB
>   expression should be like. For example, `['like', 'name', 'tester']`
>   will generate `name LIKE '%tester%'`.
>
> When the value range is given as an array, multiple LIKE predicates
>   will be generated and concatenated using AND. For example, `['like',
>   'name', ['test', 'sample']]` will generate `name LIKE '%test%' AND
>   name LIKE '%sample%'`. The method will properly quote the column name
>   and escape special characters in the values.
>
> Sometimes, you may want to add the percentage characters to the
>   matching value by yourself, you may supply a third operand `false` to
>   do so. For example, `['like', 'name', '%tester', false]` will generate
>   name `LIKE '%tester'`.